# Showing a complex function is analytic

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, proof-verification

> Define $H(z) = \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)}{t-z} dt$ where $h(t)$ is some complex valued, continuous function on $[0,1]$. Show $H(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}/[0,1]$

**My attempt:**

$H'(z) = \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{H(z + \Delta z) - H(z)}{\Delta z}$
    Equivalently, 
    $$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta z} \cdot \big( \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)}{t - z - \Delta z} dt - \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)}{t - z} dt \big)$$

Adding the integrals and making a common denominator we get

$$ \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta z} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)(t-z) - h(t)(t-z-\Delta z)}{t^2 - 2tz + z^2 + \Delta z t} dt$$ which is equal to

$$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta z} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{\Delta z}{t^2 - 2tz + z^2 + \Delta z t} dt$$

and

$$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{1}{t^2 - 2tz + z^2 + \Delta z t } dt$$

Taking the limit under the integral, we see that

$$H'(z) = \int^{1}_{0} \frac{1}{(t-z)^2}dt = \frac{1}{z-t}_{|_{0}^{1}} = \frac{1}{z^2 - z}$$

My big problem with my attempt is that I'm not sure if integrals necessarily work with any complex $z$ and if taking the limit under the integral is allowed. Can anyone give me insight?

Comment: Generally Morera's theorem is helpful for these sorts of problems.

Comment: @carmichael561The issue is that we just learned complex differentiation so that theorem is outside our toolbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument suggests that $H^\prime (z)=\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt$. So we prove that 
$$\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{H(z + \Delta z) - H(z)}{\Delta z}=\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt
.$$ Now
\begin{align}
&\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{H(z + \Delta z) - H(z)}{\Delta z}-\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta z}\left( \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)}{t - z - \Delta z} dt - \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)}{t - z} dt \right)-\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{1}{\Delta z} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)\Delta z}{(t-z-\Delta z)(t-z)} dt-\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)}{(t-z-\Delta z)(t-z)} dt-\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt\\
&=\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)\Delta z}{(t-z-\Delta z)(t-z)^2} dt.
\end{align}
Let $M=\max\limits_{0\le t\le 1}|h(t)|,$ $\delta=\operatorname{dist}(z, [0,1])>0$ for $z\not \in [0,1].$ If we take $ \Delta z$ so small, then $|t-z-\Delta z|\ge \delta/2$ for all $t\in [0,1].$ Therefore we have
\begin{align}
&\left|\int^{1}_{0} \frac{h(t)\Delta z}{(t-z-\Delta z)(t-z)^2} dt\right|\le |\Delta z|\int^{1}_{0} \frac{|h(t)|}{|t-z-\Delta z||t-z|^2} dt\\
&\le |\Delta z|\int^{1}_{0} \frac{M}{(\delta/2)\delta^2} dt\\
&=\frac{2M|\Delta z|}{\delta^3}\to 0\quad (|\Delta z|\to 0).
\end{align}
Thus we have $$
\lim_{\Delta z \to 0} \frac{H(z + \Delta z) - H(z)}{\Delta z}-\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z)^2}dt
=0$$
and we know that $H(z)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}/[0,1].$

Comment: I see my mistake. And I appreciate the proof that it is correct. Tunnel vision is the worst.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Morera's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem)...  Write $U = \mathbb C \setminus [0,1]$.

If $t \in [0,1]$, then
$$
h_t(z) =  \frac{h(t)}{t-z}
$$
is analytic in $U$.  Let $D \subset U$ be a closed disk.  Then
$$
\int_{\partial D} h_t(z)\;dz = 0\tag{1}
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_{\partial D} H(z)\;dz = \int_{\partial D}\left(\int_0^1h_t(z)\;dt\right)dz
=\int_0^1\left(\int_{\partial D} h_t(z)\;dz\right)dt = \int_0^1 0\;dt = 0 .
$$
This is true for all closed disks $D \subset U$, therefore by Morera's Theorem $H(z)$ is analytic in $U$.